# sweetAlert is not showing up

Tags: javascript, button, sweetalert

The code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Project 506</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googlesapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="sweetalert.css" type="text/css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#first").click(function () {
                    sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Message Boxes</h1>
        <input type="button" id="first" value="Just a Notification" />
        <input type="button" id="second" value="Successfully Completed!" />
        <input type="button" id="third" value="Something Went Wrong!" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not clear on why the sweetAlert animation still doesn't pop up when I click on the first button. I've tried moving the lines of `<script>` into different parts of the script, but it still doesn't work. So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check you jQuery url.
It should be:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js